# yyyymmdd - getdate retun the int

Tags: ssis

destination int value is the [columndate] - getdate

```
Create table Source_Table (  [Valyyyymmdd] [nvarchar](24) NULL  )
Create table Destination_Table ( [DestColumn]  [int] NULL  )

Insert into Source_Table (Valyyyymmdd) values
(20130503),(20120403),(00000000),(20110523),(20100715)
```

I want to get the difference with getdate()
so i used the below SQL query in my source
Expected Result SQL

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, CASE WHEN ISDATE(Valyyyymmdd) = 0 THEN getdate() ELSE Valyyyymmdd END ,   getdate()) as DestColumn 
 FROM dbo.Source_Table
```

DestColumn
479
874
0
1190
1502

but i need to get the Valyyyymmdd and do ssis derived column to get the difference in date resulting in int value.

I tryed as below

```
((DT_WSTR,24)DestColumn == "00000000" ? GETDATE() : (DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,10)DestColumn,1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,10)DestColumn,5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,10)DestColumn,7,2)))
```

Comment: can u give a sample result set?

Comment: I need the expression to return the Int ,which i have achieved using SQL query above

Comment: what is it all about?

Comment: there is an date field in source, i need to get the date diff into my destination table while moving into destination table considering today's date using SSIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DATEDIFF("d",([Valyyyymmdd] == "00000000" ? (DT_DBDATE)GETDATE() : (DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING([Valyyyymmdd ],1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Valyyyymmdd ],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(@[Valyyyymmdd ],7,2))),GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

For Me the below worked.

```
Dt == "00000000" ? (DT_DATE)GETDATE() : (DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING(Dt,1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(Dt,5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(Dt,7,2))
```

[Dt] is in place of [DestColumn]

Comment: do u mean , i have to paste this in the derived column calcuation

Comment: Yes, in your data flow, Drag a Derived column and connect it from the source.

Comment: yes i have done it. i am getting result as date .. but my expected result is the int  
DestColumn
479
874
0
1190
1502

Comment: I have edited my query with sample and example expected result. kindly check once